# Python and PLY: how to get rid of token 'XXX', defined but not used

Tags: python, ply

I'm using Python and PLY. I'm ignoring comments with this rule:

```
    def t_ANY_COMMENT(self, t):
    r'//.*$'
    pass
```

It works fine, but I get this warning:

> WARNING: Token 'COMMENT' defined, but not used

I'd like to get rid of this warning. I don't see anything in the PLY documentation to suggest what to do for this case.

Comment: Using either a lexer argument to specify an alternative lexer in the parse() function, or using a tokenfunc argument that specifies the function for getting tokens could inject extra processing to discard tokens. See this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ply-hack/TCX8sidC4ks) for others describing a similar issue

Comment: just found out that if I remove COMMENT from the list of tokens then the warning goes away.  I thought I had to put all the tokens there, but I guess I only need to put the ones there that get used by the yacc portion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my case the solution was to simply not add COMMENT to the tokens variable. I had initially thought I had to add all the tokens there. Turns out, it's only the ones used by the yacc portion. that makes sense, but the doc didn't really come out and say that.